# Rxjava return LiveData list

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Hi i am trying to use rxjava along with a LiveData that gets transformed using Map before i return it. However it saying i need to return something from inside the map.

I tried doing return `Single.just(pianoStorage.getAllFavItems())` and it complains that you are not allowed to return something?

```
override fun getFavouriteItems() : Single<LiveData<MutableList<Items>>>{
        //check if db has offers
        if (storage.getAllFavItems().value!!.isEmpty()){
             getAllFavItems().map {
                 {offers : ItemsResponse ->
                     storage.saveAllItemsLists(offers)
                     Single.just(storage.getAllFavItems())
                 }
             }.subscribe(
                     {offers ->
                         return@subscribe
                     }
             )
        }else{
            return Single.just(storage.getAllFavItems())
        }
    }
```

The code below basically checks my persistent database if i have some items there and if not, fetch  it from the network using retrofit(the getAllFavItems())

This network call gets all the list of items and then what i need to do is first save it to the storage and then get only the favourite items from it afterwords using the below:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE state = 'Fav'")
    fun getAllFavItems(): LiveData<MutableList<Item>>
```

Comment: An observable that contains essentially another observable (live data)? Why would you need something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `DAO` definition to:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE state = 'Fav'")
fun getAllFavItems(): Flowable<MutableList<Item>>
```

You can do something like this:

```
getAllFavItems()
    .flatMap({
        if(it.isEmpty()) {
            getAllFavItems().toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.XXX)
                .doOnNext({storage.saveAllItemsLists(it)})
                .map {/*TODO: convert from ItemsResponse to List<Item>*/}
        } else {
            Flowable.just(it)
        }
    })
```

The code emits changes to the favorite items. If there are 0 favorite items it will call the `getAllFavItems()` function and insert the results into db (inserting the results will cause `getAllFavitems()` to emit again).

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
getAllFavItems().map { offers : ItemsResponse ->
    storage.saveAllItemsLists(offers)
    Single.just(storage.getAllFavItems())
}
```

You have twice `{` and `}` inside `map`.

Comment: That did not seem to work and instead says i have a type missmatch error stating how it expects a function<MutableList...>, out(???) but found LiveData<MutableList> which is correct?!?!?!